# OSX Sierra hangs when accessing Printers

Tags: macos, printing

there is a situation that I can't resolve. It is related to the "Printer & Scanner" service on the Sierra. When I upgraded to it any app which tries to resolve the printer list crashes, including the System Preferences.

I've already tried copying the default settings file:

`sudo cp /etc/cups/cupsd.conf /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.old`

`sudo cp /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.default /etc/cups/cupsd.conf`

That didn't help.. So in a nutshell, I can't use the printing on my laptop, including 'export to pdf' on Chrome.
Do you know what might be happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS?  It seems 10.12.1 had some fixes for printing included, so it is relevant whether you are talking about 10.12 or 10.12.1

Comment: It's for 10.12.1; I'm still trying to figure where's the problem, so it seems it can't resolve the `lpstat -p`

Comment: Ok, turns out I had old Canon printer installed. It got messed up after the upgrade, so I found every file and folder under /Library which was related to this Canon device and removed it.
Didn't fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot to Safe Mode by holding shift on boot.
2. In **System Preferences** → **Printers & Scanners**, right-click on any printer and choose **Reset printing system…** and enter your administrator password.

   [image]

If you still can't open the printers list in Safe Mode, temporarily move the contents of /Library/Printers elsewhere, reboot to Safe Mode once more, then try the steps above again.

Comment: @Icon Resetting the printing system removes all printers as well.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help either. In Safe mode it's the same as in the normal one..

Comment: This has worked for me even without going to the Safe Mode. It took ages for Printers & Scanners dialog to show up and then again ages for the right click menu to show (I had no printers appearing in the list but the menu still shows the Reset printing system... even if the list is empty) and then finally it started working.

Comment: Did not work here, same as @will. Even did a repair installation, but this did not cure it either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither safe boot (as explained in grgarside's answer) nor resetting cups (as shown in the question) fixed the problem.

This worked for me:

I [reinstalled macOS from repair mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) which is possible without data loss. To enter repair mode, start the Mac, then immediately press cmd-R. You can release the keys when you see the Apple.

After that, accessing the printer preferences still shows the spinning wheel, but be patient, after a long while (about 3-4 minutes in my case) the printer preferences should eventually get loaded. Then, right-click in the printer list, and select *Reset printing system*. After that, the printer preferences should be back to normal.